# Android numberpicker getting stuck

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I have a numberpicker dialog to select hours and minutes (15 minutes interval). It works fine on large screens but on small screens and older devices it gets stuck if I try to scroll using touch.

[image]

I am extending the android.widget.NumberPicker and reducing the font size which helps on some devices.

```
public class TimerNumberPicker extends android.widget.NumberPicker {

    public TimerNumberPicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TimerNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    private void updateView(View view) {
        if(view instanceof EditText){
            ((EditText) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16);
            view.setTag(FontUtil.TAG_CONDENSED_LIGHT);
            FontUtil.getInstence(getContext()).setFontByTag(view);
        }
    }
}
```

What makes it more complicated is that the minutes have only values `(0, 15, 30, 45)` and I have to `setWrapSelectorWheel to false`?

I am thinking if it will be possible to always show the up and down arrows and then disabling scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to an Edittext with the type of number, and use a Toast if the client put a number upper or below of your range. It's more elegant visually, and that will not give you any problem at all

Answer (score 0):

you can use Fantastic **PickView** library

See [PickView](https://github.com/MostafaAnter/PickView)

This is a helper lib for us to pick date or province like IOS system WheelView widget.

Comment: Advertising yourself there, ain't ya?

Comment: no i'm not the owner of library i just use it and it work perfect

Comment: As @Vucko suggests, you should indicate that you are the owner on the library and provide a good example of how this can help: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298734/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-my-own-library-as-part-of-a-real-answer

Comment: @antonio He stated clearly he's NOT the owner of that library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could solve it using a `TimePicker`.

This could be the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Set"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

While the dialog could be included in a normal alert:

```
private void showTimePicker(){
    final View dialogView = View.inflate(getActivity(), <time_picker_container_layout_id>, null);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

    dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

            String time = timePicker.getCurrentHour()+":"+timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

            dateTime.setText(time);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }});


    TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

    timePicker.setCurrentHour(<default_hour>);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(<default_minute>);

    alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

If you need to show just the 15', you can round the picked minutes to the closest valid value.

The scrollView in the layout will reduce problems related the picker size.
I hope it helped.